# Magento2 in How to Remove Duplicate button in product create?

Tags: magento2, product, admin, adminform

**How to Remove Duplicate button in product Create/Edit page - Magento2.**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php` and `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/Save.php` you see that on the location where the button is created it checks if the product is duplicable:

```
if (!$this->getRequest()->getParam('popup') && $this->getProduct()->isDuplicable()) {
    $options[] = [
        'id' => 'duplicate-button',
        'label' => __('Save & Duplicate'),
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => [
                'button' => ['event' => 'saveAndDuplicate', 'target' => '[data-form=edit-product]'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

So the most obvious way I could think of is to make sure the `$product->isDuplicable()` will return false. It is a public method so you could use a plugin / interceptor to let it return false, or hook into the product loading and do something like `$product->setIsDuplicable(false);`

Note the `isDuplicable()` is a method of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` and is not defined in it's service contract. Haven't tested it yet, but I'm not sure that writing an interceptor for the service contract will pick it up.

Comment: Thanx for the Answer but I checked both files code remove but it's not working. plugin things I don't know how it uses. can you explain about it?

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of Giel Berkers answer:

MyCompany/MyModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="disable_product_duplicate" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\ProductPlugin" sortOrder="100"/>
</type>
```

MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\ProductPlugin

```
namespace MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin;

class ProductPlugin
{
    /**
     * Checks product can be duplicated
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function afterIsDuplicable(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $result)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```